# Deleting end of line if column starts with character

Tags: awk, sed, columns

I have a large file, where the second column has some lines that need to be truncated. Currently it is:

```
10 10:135524264:C:G 0 135524264 C G
10 rs55726203:135524334:A:G 0 135524334 A G
```

If the **second** column starts with '**rs**', I need to delete everything after the colon of that column. So I need the output to be:

```
10 10:135524264:C:G 0 135524264 C G
10 rs55726203 0 135524334 A G
```

I'm relatively new to unix, and can only find forum questions that target part of what I need. I have `sed 's/:.*//'` to delete after the colon, but can't figure out how to target that specifically to the second column lines that start with 'rs'.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier with `awk`:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^rs/ {sub(/:.*/,"",$2)} 1' file
10 10:135524264:C:G 0 135524264 C G
10 rs55726203 0 135524334 A G
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned sed, here's one way to do it. In general, navigating to the Nth column given the separator S, is done like this: '^[^S]*S[^S]*S...' with optional parentheses around various parts if one needs to remember them. There are other ways, but since N=2, this will do.

```sh
sed -r 's/^([^ ]* )(rs[^ :]*):[^ ]*/\1\2/' file
```

Once I reach the 2nd column, I keep only what starts with 'rs' and continues with chars other than the separator space and colon. Note my ':[^ ]*' instead of ':.*', used to not delete the remaining columns.

**Warning: This only works for columns that don't contain the separator**, like your example. If you have cells with escaped separator in quotes, like 'text *"text text"* text', please consider using a dedicated tool and not sed or even awk!